# Django migration fails with InvalidForeignKey: "unique constraint" error for "django_site"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I've run into a django migration problem.  Please help if you have any idea how to get around this!

I upgraded Django from 2.2.7 to 3.2.  In the new system I continued work, adding a number of new models.  I added a new model called "Space" which has a one-to-one relationship with the Django Site model.  This all worked on my development machine (PostgreSQL 9.6) and staging machine (PostgreSQL 9.4, although I had to work around a minor incompatibility with Django 3.2).

However, on production we have upgraded from an old version of PostgreSQL 9.4, to PostreSQL 12.  Now the migration won't run! It gives the following error:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying appname.0039_auto_20210521_1034...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "django_site"
```

This is the part of the migration file 0039_auto_20210521_1034 that must be causing the problem...?

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Space',
            fields=[
                ('site', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='spaces', serialize=False, to='sites.Site', verbose_name='site')),
                ('virtual', models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)),
            ],
        ),
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Space(models.Model):
    """Space model is OneToOne related to Site model."""
    site = models.OneToOneField(
        Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,
        related_name='space', verbose_name='site')

    virtual = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=True, default=False,
                                  help_text="The kind of space that events take place in.")
```

Anyone got an idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance for your help, I need it!

Comment: Since `site` is unique, you can only make *at most* one link to the same `Site`, not two or more.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that somehow the database copy I was working with had mysteriously lost the constraints on that table (and maybe other tables, too, I didn't check the other ones).

I didn't perform the database copy, so I don't know how that could have happened.  If anyone has a theory, do tell.

But that resolves the problem, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this, the key was simply listing the constraints with

```
SELECT con.oid, con.conname, con.connamespace, con.contype
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname = 'playaevents'
             AND rel.relname = 'django_site';
```

There were two rows returned in the originial database, and 0 rows in the copy.